# Using supplier for refactoring method passing function as parameter

Tags: java, java-8

I have duplicate method that I want to refactor. The only difference is the usage of findValidTransactions() and findActiveTransactions() which is defined in the same class.

```
protected Map<String, String> originalMethod() {
      // some same codes
       for (Transaction transaction : findValidTransactions()) {
           keyboardMap.put(String.valueOf(transaction.getId()), 
      transaction.getName());
    }
    return keyboardMap;
}

protected Map<String, String> copiedMethod() {
      // some same codes
    for (Transaction transaction : findActiveTransactions()) {
        keyboardMap.put(String.valueOf(transaction.getId()), transaction.getName());
    }
    return keyboardMap;
}
```

I tried to refactor using Supplier as a parameter:

```
protected Map<String, String> originalMethod(Supplier<List<AcsIssuer>> listFunction) {
      // some same codes
    for (Transaction transaction : listFunction.get()) {
        keyboardMap.put(String.valueOf(transaction.getId()), transaction.getName());
    }
    return keyboardMap;
}
```

So everytime I call the originalMethod I will just pass the reference to that method. Like the following code:

```
originalMethod(super::findValidTransactions)
```

Is this correct or feasible?

Comment: "Is this correct" Add a unit test and find out. That's how you're supposed to refactor.

Comment: The original code did not use a `super` call, so why are you suddenly using `super::` instead of `this::`? Besides that, the code is obvious enough, to conclude that it does  contain the common code of the two methods. You don’t need the `Supplier` though, as passing in the `List<AcsIssuer>` would do as well.

Answer (score 1):

One way to refactor that would be passing the transactions as an argument to the method, as in :

```
Map<String, String> transactionIdToNameMap(List<? extends Transaction> transactions) {
    return transactions.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(transaction ->
                    String.valueOf(transaction.getId()), Transaction::getName));
}
```

Comment: how will I call findActiveTransactions() or findValidTransactions()

Comment: @rlchaps26t some point in time, you need to call `transactionIdToNameMap`, that's where you pass them.